# =NAN after summing up with comma separator Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascripting. but When I add up the values in the textfield. It gives me a NAN.
What can I do with this?

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#family_home,#home_contents,#motor_vehicle', function() 
{
    updateTotal();
});

var updateTotal =function() 
{
    var a = $('#family_home').val();
    $('#family_home').val(a.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+        (?!\d))/g, ","));
    var b = $('#home_contents').val();
    $('#home_contents').val(b.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+    (?!\d))/g, ","));
    var c = $('#motor_vehicle').val();
    $('#motor_vehicle').val(c.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    var d = document.getElementById('Total');

    d.value=0;
    d.value=parseFloat(d.value);
    d.value=parseFloat('#family_home') + parseFloat('#home_contents') + parseFloat('#motor_vehicle');
}
```

Please help me. or revise my code.

Comment: `parseFloat('#family_home')` etc. returns `NaN`. Why are you passing a jQuery selector to `parseFloat()`?

Comment: Form control values are always strings, there is no need for `toString`.

Comment: @MattBall getting picky the OP is trying to parse a non-numeric string that happens to be in the fomat of a jquery selecor.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're getting a bit confused with what you are cleaning, and summing

try breaking the code into sections:

1. Get the values
2. Clean them
3. Sum them

You should end up with something like this

**EDIT:** Corrected the regex to clean values and added some formatting to the total as per @CrazySheep's comments

```
var updateTotal = function() 
{
    // get the values
    var a = $('#family_home').val();
    var b = $('#home_contents').val();
    var c = $('#motor_vehicle').val();
    var d = document.getElementById('Total');

    // clean (i.e. remove commas)
    a = a.replace(/,/g, "");
    b = b.replace(/,/g, "");
    c = c.replace(/,/g, "");

    // calculate the total
    var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c);

    // format the total (comma separators) and update the html element 
    d.value = total.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: As an additional improvement, I'd suggest using meaningful variable names. The code would be more readable and therefore maintainable by using `home`, `contents`, `vehcile` and `totalAmount` rather than `a`,`b`,`c` & `d`. But that is very much a side note.

Comment: (I know its 2 days old but) your clean section adds commas back in - which parseFloat will ignore and return an incorrect number.

Comment: Thanks @Crazysheep, I've updated my answer so that the regex that places the comma separator is only applied **after** the total has been calculated

Comment: @jasonscript no worries, your answer is much more complete and better formatted right now, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

```
d.value=parseFloat('#family_home') + parseFloat('#home_contents') + parseFloat('#motor_vehicle');
```

should be

```
d.value=parseFloat($('#family_home').val()) + parseFloat($('#home_contents').val()) + parseFloat($('#motor_vehicle').val());
```

You also have a lot of redundant parseFloat() calls and toString() calls as RobG pointed out.

Edit: Remove commas first.

```
d.value=parseFloat(a.replace(/,/g, '')) + parseFloat(b.replace(/,/g, '')) + parseFloat(c.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Comment: Thank you for this.But why is it that it only sum up the first number before the comma? for example 11,232 + 11,213 = 22

Comment: @user3192596 I know its been 2 days already but if you're still wondering its because parseFloat will only convert numerical characters.

Hence it will only convert up to the comma because the comma isn't a number. One solution is to use regex to remove the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#family_home,#home_contents,#motor_vehicle', function() 
{
    updateTotal();
});

var updateTotal =function() 
{
    var a = $('#family_home').val();
    $('#family_home').val(a.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+        (?!\d))/g, ","));
    var b = $('#home_contents').val();
    $('#home_contents').val(b.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+    (?!\d))/g, ","));
    var c = $('#motor_vehicle').val();
    $('#motor_vehicle').val(c.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    var d = document.getElementById('Total');

    d.value=0;
    d.value=parseFloat(d.value);
    d.value= parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c);
}
```

Comment: I know this is 2 days old already but the way you pass in the variables a, b and c will contain commas. Hence him running a.toString().replace(/,/g, "").

I've edited my answer to take this into account too (I didn't look too closely at the regex the first time and his second replace reinserts commas)